# Algorithm to cluster 2D points into bounding-box decomposition

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, point-clouds

[image]

I'm looking for an algorithm that takes the unstructured 2D point set as illustrated above and gives me a decomposition into bounding boxes as shown below. The bounding boxes may overlap, but the algorithm should nevertheless try to find a tight fit (it does not need to be the best one possible, but a good one).

I already tried to work with K-Means but that doesn't give me useful results as I'd need to know already how many clusters I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to achieve this. The one I'd use is to apply the [RANSAC](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) algorithm in order to sequentially fit Oriented Bounding Boxes (OBB) to the data. By adopting this approach you can even improve the sample selection by computing a constrained Delaunay triangulation on your data, thus discarding bigger edges when fitting the OBB.

Alternatively, you can apply the Alpha-shape algorithm on the entire set of points and start decomposing in smaller shapes, but this requires the definition of an optimal alpha value which is not trivial.